# RDLC no header and first row after deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

i have developed rdlc report in asp.net mvc it works fine in my local machine it look like :
[image: rdlc report in mylocal machine]

after deploy to windows server r2  there is no header and first row
[image: There is no header and first row]

Source code for Report for report

```
 public ActionResult M29_Post(int Year, int Month)
    {




        //Step 3 : Create Report DataSources
        ReportDataSource dsExclude = new ReportDataSource();
        dsExclude.Name = "DSExclude";
        dsExclude.Value = dsE.Tables["ExcludeM29"];

        //Step 4 : Bind DataSources into Report
        localReport.DataSources.Add(dsExclude);

        //Step 5 : Call render method on local Report to generate report contents in Bytes array
        string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
         "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
         "</DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        string mimeType = String.Empty;
        byte[] renderedBytes;
        string encoding = String.Empty;
        string fileNameExtension = String.Empty;
        //Render the report           
        renderedBytes = localReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);


        //Step 6 : Set Response header to pass filename that will be used while saving report.
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
         "attachment; filename=M29-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".pdf");

        //Step 7 : Return file content result
        return new FileContentResult(renderedBytes, mimeType);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: added a portion of the code